# Refusal to pay my month in hand due to missing contract

Tags: resignation, contracts

Looking for advice. I'm based in the UK and I have worked for a company for 22 years. I handed in my 4 weeks notice and asked my manager how much wages I would be due. They told me I would be paid from the 1st of June to the 17th which is my last day. I'm 100% sure I worked a month in hand but they are saying they don't have my original contract of employment.

The only one they have is copy of one from 2006 when I was promoted which says nothing about what I worked upon starting the job. I've raised a grievance but I'm not confident anything will come of it.

Comment: What does 'a month in hand' mean?

Comment: Do you have a copy of your original contract?

Comment: You think they owe you for a month’s salary from 22 years ago? Do you have a copy of the first contract? 22 years ago, it might be printed in a folder at your home?

Comment: Without your copy of the original contract you have no evidence. Unless you have pay evidence ie bank statements payslips etc which may show what happened.

Comment: Are you saying that when you started this job you were paid one month's wage at the end of the second month?

Answer (score 10):

Your payslips should state what period they cover, as well as the pay date.

If you're always being paid in the current month, then there's no evidence you're being paid in arrears.